# How to extend Google Analytics file with each view in ios?

Tags: ios, google-analytics

How to extend Google Analytics file with each view in ios ? I'm new to iOS and confused with the syntax.

I want to extend with this viewcontroller

```
@interface IXComposeViewController ()<UITextFieldDelegate,UIActionSheetDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,IXScrollViewDelegate>
```

So how should I combine these two extension?

```
 @interface IXComposeViewController : GAITrackedViewController
```

Confused with syntax,please help.

Comment: is `IXComposeViewController` a custom `UIViewController` that you created?

Comment: yes. IXComposeViewController  is my custom controller

Comment: I want to extend GAITrackedViewController with IXComposeViewController.

Comment: can you post more code please?

Comment: can you please edit the question and post the whole code? what exactly is the problem besides your confusion with the syntax? are you getting errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did it exactly right, for screen tracking in Google Analytics you only need to perform two simple steps:

1. the `UIViewController` that should be tracked needs to inherit from `GAITrackedViewController`, so your suggested syntax is correct: `@interface IXComposeViewController : GAITrackedViewController`
2. add the line `self.screenName = @"screen: IXComposeViewController"; // or any other string` in your `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`

To make it clear, in your **header**-file, you need to extend `GAITrackedViewController`, so it would look somewhat like this:

#### IXComposeViewController.h

```
#import "GAITrackedViewController.h"

@interface IXComposeViewController : GAITrackedViewController
// declare public properties and methods
@end
```

#### IXComposeViewController.m

```
@implementation IXComposeViewController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  self.screenName = @"About Screen";
}
@end
```

Comment: Im confused with syntax, can you extend GAITrackedViewController with @interface IXComposeViewController ()<UITextFieldDelegate,UIActionSheetDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,IXScrollViewDelegate>

Comment: `@interface IXComposeViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate,UIActionSheetDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDe‌​legate,IXScrollViewDelegate>` is in your **.m** file, right?

Comment: yes, we need to declare "screenName" ? got an error": Property 'screenName' not found on object of type 'IXInBoxViewController *'"

Comment: What's the problem actually? Doesn't it work when you implement the .h file in the way I am suggesting?

Comment: I used same code    self.screenName = @"About Screen";    
 you suggested in viewwillppear(), but got an error that "screenName' not found", So I need to declare screenName externally?

Comment: Yes I cleaned the project now its worked. Thanks a lot.